# Why is my TextToSpeech not making sound?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, deprecated

I am developing an app that requires text to speech. So I read a few tts tutorials and did this:

```
public void buttonClick (View view) {
    TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech (this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener () {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

        }
    });

    tts.setLanguage (Locale.UK);
    tts.speak ("Hello World", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

However, when I run the app and click the button, no voice is heard, only the "click" sound of the button. This also implies that the speaker is switched on.

I guess this is because `speak(String, int, HashMap<String, String>)` is deprecated. This guess is proved wrong when I look at the docs:

```
 /** @deprecated As of API level 21, replaced by
 *         {@link #speak(CharSequence, int, Bundle, String)}.
 */
```

And my app's minimum SDK version is API18 and my device's android version is Android 4.3. That means `speak` is not deprecated. The deprecation is maybe just a bug of Android Studio.

I wonder why it makes no sound and how I can fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void buttonClick (View view) {
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech (this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener () {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
     // change required.Initialization has to finish first.   
     if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
     tts.setLanguage (Locale.UK);
     tts.speak ("Hello World", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
     }
    }
});



}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this example.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   TextToSpeech t1;

   Button b1;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

      t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
         @Override
         public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
               t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
         }
      });

      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

            t1.speak("Hi dear its working", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
         }
      });
   }

   public void onPause(){
      if(t1 !=null){
         t1.stop();
         t1.shutdown();
      }
      super.onPause();
   }


}
```

and xml file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   android:transitionGroup="true">


   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Text to Speech"
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So what did I do wrong? Can my results be reproduced?

Comment: you should call texttospeech in side on create method    t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
         @Override
         public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
               t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
         }
      });

Comment: @Sweeper in your code you are initialize your TextToSpeech inside button  on click which is  bad way you should initialize when activity created either inside onCreate() or onStart() method of activity.